# Question about historical figures and timeline in "Ever After: A Cinderella Story"

Tags: plot-explanation, character, ever-after

I understand that *Ever After: A Cinderella Story* is a fairytale; however, the film included actual historical figures and references in the film.  The historical figures do not coincide with movie timeline.  Here are just a few examples:

The King of France is called *Francis*, which I am assuming is Francis I of France.  His son, called *Prince Henry* (assuming to be Henry II) is portrayed as an only child.  Francis I actually had 7 children, 5 of which survived into adulthood and the oldest son, also Francis would be next in line to the throne at the time of the movie.

Leonardo Da Vinci is portrayed as a very old man and is a guest of the King of France.  Prince Henry appears to be 18-20 yrs old in the movie; however, Da Vinci died in 1519 and the actual Henry II was born in 1516, so Henry would have only been 3 yrs old during Da Vinci's visit.

The basis of the movie is Danielle (a peasant girl) and Prince Henry's romance.  Henry II actually married Catherine De Medici...who is a far cry from a peasant girl.

Does anyone know if these characters (the royals) could be based on any other figures or be set in a different time other than a *suggested* time line of early 16th century?  I know that with Da Vinci in the movie, it should be narrowed down, but the timeline seems to be all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are historical figures in this movie, you just have to accept the fact that the time line is never going to add up.  I agree that Francis is more than likely Francis I and Henry is Henry II.  Since the characters in the movie are extremely loosely based on historical figures, you just have to take it with a grain of salt that the time line will never make sense.